# Generating android build showing me an error

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

I am using IntelliJ to develop flutter app. When I am trying to generate build but it is showing me an error.

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_crashlytics'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)
```

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) for full error message. Also check https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-geolocator/issues/127

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error and the fix is very easy.
Go to the `android/build.gradle` and check if the following lines have the same version (or newer):

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Furthermore go to `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and double-check the gradle value:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

That's it.

Let me know ;)